# Undefined variable: discounts in /home/thehouseofarts/public_html/azistaonlinestore/catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/featured.tpl on line 40

Tags: opencart

Undefined variable: discounts in /home/thehouseofarts/public_html/azista online store/catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/featured.tpl on line 40

Answer (score 0):

You may be updated your opencart application but not properly updated

Comment: <?php if ($discounts) { ?>
        <br />
        <div class="discounts">
          <?php foreach ($product['discounts'] as $discount) { ?>
          <?php echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?><br />
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

Comment: <?php if (count($discounts)>0) { ?> <br />

Comment: try like the above

Comment: again am getting same error.Actually i want to add product discount bundles in featured products which are shown in home page